# This application is available to over 0 devices

Tags: android, manifest

**My apk is active**

I just published my application and when I go to the Play Store web page, it states my application isn't compatible with any of my devices : [Sharelist](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.plumillonforge.android.sharelist)

[image]

So I check the Play publish page and I got "This application is available to over 0 devices"
[image]

I'm not doing anything fancy on my Manifest :

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.plumillonforge.android.sharelist"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="15" />

<supports-screens 
    android:smallScreens="true" 
    android:normalScreens="true" 
    android:largeScreens="true"
    android:anyDensity="true"/>

<application
    android:icon="@drawable/launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/SharelistTheme">

    <activity
        android:name=".PagerActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
            <data android:scheme="file" />
            <data android:mimeType="*/*" />
            <data android:pathPattern=".*\\.shl" />
            <data android:pathPattern=".*\\..*\\.shl" />
            <data android:pathPattern=".*\\..*\\..*\\.shl" />
            <data android:pathPattern=".*\\..*\\..*\\..*\\.shl" />
            <data android:host="*" />
        </intent-filter>

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <data android:mimeType="text/plain" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity
        android:name=".ListActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_apps_list" />

    <activity
        android:name=".fragment.FilePickerActivity"
        android:label="@string/choose_shl_file" />

    <activity android:name="com.google.ads.AdActivity"
        android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize"/>
</application>
</manifest>
```

Comment: what do you mean by android.hardware.touchscreen feature? is that system default or else you added some feature.

Comment: I didn't add anything, this is a default feature

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out the problem

It was the Google Admob jar file include which was causing this weird behavior : I created a folder in my src/, add the jar and include it in my build path

It seems the build was oki but the Play Store got confused

So I delete the jar and build path, then created a libs/ folder in my project root then add it to the build path and it works now :)

**You musn't add you jar file in the src/ folder (or any children folder) and add it to your build path**

Answer (score 0):

Hey add the following code to Manifest file and give a try. It should work.

```
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.touchscreen"  android:required="false" />
```

and try to remove the Copy Protection in the Play Store Publish page also.

Just give a try.

Comment: Thx I saw this solution too but it didn't work, I also don'y have copy protection. I found the solution and I will post the answer